# Sub accounts sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables
Table 1

```
Account     mainaccount
-------      --- 
A            Null
B            A
C            A
D            B
```

Second table
Table

```
Account     cost
--------     --
C            10
D            20
```

Need this result

```
Account
A   30
B   20
C   10
D   20
```

Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a recursive CTE and aggregation:

```
with cte as (
      select t.account, t.account as paired_account
      from table1 t
      union all
      select cte.account, t.mainaccount
      from cte join
           table1 t
           on cte.paired_account = t.account
     )
select cte.account, sum(t2.cost)
from cte join
     table2 t2
     on t2.account = cte.paired_account
group by cte.account;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this (I tried this with temp table but replace them with your real tables.):

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Account') IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
      DROP TABLE #Account
    END;

IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#AccountCost') IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
      DROP TABLE #AccountCost
    END;

CREATE TABLE #Account (AcctId varchar(3) NOT NULL, MainAcctId varchar(3) NULL)
CREATE TABLE #AccountCost (AcctId varchar(3)NOT NULL, cost int null)

INSERT INTO #Account (AcctId, MainAcctId)
  values ('A', NULL),('B', 'A'),('C', 'A'),('D', 'B')

insert into #AccountCost(AcctId  , cost)
values ('C',  10)
,('D',  20)

;WITH cte 
AS
(
  SELECT e.AcctId, e.AcctId as ChildAcctId 
  FROM #Account e
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
     c.AcctId 
     ,e.AcctId as ChildAcctId
  FROM #Account e
    INNER JOIN cte c ON c.ChildAcctId = e.MainAcctId
)
SELECT  c.AcctId
       , sum(s.cost)
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN #AccountCost as s
ON s.AcctId = c.ChildAcctId
group by c.AcctId
```

Comment: Thank you.....somthing else please if I want to show only A result how can i do it?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShkear use where condition at the end WHERE c.AcctId = 'A'